# Surjectivity of a function considering $f \circ h=Id_Y$

Tags: analysis

\begin{align} f: \mathbb{R}^2 &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \\ (x,y) & \longmapsto x+y \end{align}
**Question: Is this function surjective?**

It seems clear to me that this function must be surjective, because the point $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ maps to the entire codomain $\mathbb{R}$ under the addition given by function. But I wanted to try a different approach:

**Question (refined): Is this function surjective, using  $\ f\circ h=Id_\mathbb{R}$**

Here are my steps. I defined $h$ as the following function:
\begin{align}h: \mathbb{R} &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \\ x &\longmapsto (x,0) \end{align}

Such that:
\begin{align} (f \circ h)(x)=x&=f(h(x)) \\ &=f(x,0)=x \end{align}
Are these steps correct, or aren't they even valid?

**Note**: I am very new to this subject and in my homework assigment I am also allowed to use examples and counter examples, but I am always very eager to expand my knowledge to such sentences as introduced as above.

Namely: if a right inverse exists, such that $f \circ h= Id_Y$, where $h$ is called the *right inverse*, then the function $f$ is surjective.

Comment: It's a correct argument, and indeed if a right inverse exists, then the function is surjective (the converse holds too, unless you reject the axiom of choice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second argument is fully correct.

One remark about the first one though. You say "this function must be surjective, because the point $(x,y) \in {\mathbb R}^2$ maps to the entire codomain ${\mathbb R}$". The formulation is a bit weird: it's not the point that maps anywhere, but the function. But anyway, this is not really an argument, but just a restatement of what surjectivity means. To really show that the function $f$ maps to the entire codomain, you'd have to take an element of the codomain, say $x$, and find an element of the domain that maps to $x$. Of course, you take $(x,0)$ and then you again have exactly your second argument again.

This way you also see that the first and second way of arguing are fundamentally the same.

Comment: I appreciate your insight a lot. You're right, in my first statement I only restated what surjectivity means. Especially your line about "To really show that the function f maps to the entire codomain, you'd have to take an element of the codomain, say x, and find an element of the domain that maps to x." did clear things up again for me. I wasn't certain if the point I have chosen would satisfy this problem, but I feel better about such problems now.